Laravel searh function does not show all results
I have created a search with Laravel 11 that is in a controller and has a join to another table. However, with the join some of the results do not show .
This is my controller:
public function search(Request $request){
 $query = $request->input('query');
 $result = Catagory::where('catagories.name','like',"%$query%")
  ->orWhere('size','like',"%$query%")
  ->orWhere('email','like',"%$query%")
   ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$query%")
  ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'catagories.catagory_id')
  ->select('products.*','products.name as products_name')
  ->get();
                    
return view('search.results')->with('result', $result);

}
This is the blade:
<form action="{{route('search')}}" method= 'GET'>
 @csrf
<input type="text" name="query" id="query">
<button class="btn btn-primary-sm" type="submit">Search</button>

This is the route:
Route::get('/search/search', [CatagoriesController::class,'search'])->name('search');

When I run the above searh I get the catagories.name and (the join) the products_name. Furthermore, if I remove the join I get all the data size, email, description which I do not get with the join
As I said above removing the join, it work but without  products_name, I checked the $request and the $query with a dd.

Try This out
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->input('query');
    
        // Validate the input query
        if (empty($query)) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['query' => 'Search query cannot be empty']);
        }
    
        // Build the search query
        $result = Catagory::where('catagories.name', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('catagories.size', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('catagories.email', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('catagories.description', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'catagories.catagory_id')
            ->select('products.*', 'catagories.name as catagory_name', 'catagories.size', 'catagories.email', 'catagories.description')
            ->get();
    
        // Return the results to the view
        return view('search.results')->with('result', $result);
    }

Then on your view
@if($result->isEmpty())
        <p>No results found.</p>
    @else
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Category Name</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($result as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $item->products_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->catagory_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endif


Please try it this query first use select then join and last your where statement
public function search(Request $request){
 $query = $request->query;
 $result = DB::table('categories')
  ->select(''catagories.name','products.*','products.name as products_name')
  ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'catagories.catagory_id')
  ->where('catagories.name','like',"%$query%")
  ->orWhere('size','like',"%$query%")
  ->orWhere('email','like',"%$query%")
  ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$query%")
  ->get();

return view('search.results')->with('result', $result);

also when search before using dd($result); to confirm your query result.

Thank you, mamaye your solution worked well much appreciated.

Thank you user24966425 I will note this for future reference

@Phenox , if this query works then please mark the answer as accepted so that others can take reference from it.
